# Which is more efficient, INTEGER or one character TEXT?

Tags: android, sqlite

Let's say I have a spinner with 4 options from which the user can choose:

- apple,
- banana,
- clementine,
- dragon fruit.

I'll need to store that option in the table in SQLite database. I can assign to those options either values 0, 1, 2, 3 or letters a, b, c, d.

The question is, in terms of space, is it better to create a column with datatype INTEGER and store numbers in it? Does it make a big difference if I define the column as TEXT and store one character values in it?

**EDIT:** I'm planning to upload the data from this SQLite database stored on Android device to PostgreSQL database located on a server and the corresponding column there is of a Char(1) datatype. Should I change the type of that one too or will it be easy to somehow make a conversion between let's say 2 and 'c' when inserting new rows to PostgreSQL table based on the rows from SQLite table?

Comment: Why not just store it in Postgres and fetch it using Android? I'm not seeing the need for the other way around

Comment: Because I'll need to store the data somewhere until the user connects to the Internet and then the data can be uploaded to the server :)

Comment: Sure, but syncing a sqlite database in android is an age old problem. You're likeky better off with Couchbase Lite, Realm Sync, or Firebase

Comment: Well, sadly, I was told I _have to_ use Postgres to store data on the server, so I'll need to find a way to sync it somehow :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [SQLite file format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format), the values `0` and `1` need one byte less than `2`, `3`, `'a'`, ..., `'d'`.

However, on a mobile device, you will never have enough data that the difference would matter.
Use whatever is easiest to handle.